# How To Group Object Using reduce Function javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, reduce

**I have been stuck on this for 8 days now.**

Let's say here is my response object array:

```
var items = [
{
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
},
{
    name: 'hp-44',
    price: 100,
    id: 10,
},
{
    name: 'acer-33',
    price: 250,
    id: 33,
},
{
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
},
{
    name: 'acer-33',
    price: 250,
    id: 33,
},
{
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
},
]
```

So far i have managed to make a function using reduce to accumulate the price. Here is the code that does this:

```
var obj = items.reduce( function (allItems, currentItem) {
var item_name = currentItem.name;
var item_price = currentItem.price;


var total_prices = allItems[item_price] = (allItems[item_price] || 0) +   
item_price;


var result = {};

result[item_name] = {
    item_price:  total_prices,
}


return Object.assign(allItems, result);
}, {} )
```

Although this works, it does not return the results i want, instead it returns this:

```
{
'100': 100,
'200': 600,
'250': 500,
'dell-66': { item_price: 600 },
'hp-44': { item_price: 100 },
'acer-33': { item_price: 500 } 
 }
```

Here is what i intended and need it to be (without the extra key/values at the top):

```
{
'dell-66': { item_price: 600 },
'hp-44': { item_price: 100 },
'acer-33': { item_price: 500 } 
 }
```

**How Can i achieve this please?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it like this.

```js
const items = [{
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
  }, {
    name: 'hp-44',
    price: 100,
    id: 10,
  }, {
    name: 'acer-33',
    price: 250,
    id: 33,
  }, {
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
  }, {
    name: 'acer-33',
    price: 250,
    id: 33,
  }, {
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
  },
].reduce((res, obj) => {
  res[obj.name] = { 
    item_price: (obj.name in res ? res[obj.name].item_price : 0) + obj.price 
  }
  return res;
}, {})

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Holy Moly! This Works! Thank you! But could you maybe explain what had been the problem with my code?

Comment: @ViveeOmomi Well, to start off with, `allItems[item_price]` is looking for a key of `item_price` in `allItems`. Aka: `{ '100': value}` not (As i think you were going for) a key where its value is `item_price`, Aka: `{ key: 100 }`

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code:

```js
var items = [
{
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
},
{
    name: 'hp-44',
    price: 100,
    id: 10,
},
{
    name: 'acer-33',
    price: 250,
    id: 33,
},
{
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
},
{
    name: 'acer-33',
    price: 250,
    id: 33,
},
{
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
},
]

let result = items.reduce((result, current) => {
 if(!result[current.name]){
  result[current.name] = { item_price: 0 };
 }
 result[current.name].item_price += current.price;
 return result;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the map function for this.
Please try following code.

```js
var items = [
{
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
},
{
    name: 'hp-44',
    price: 100,
    id: 10,
},
{
    name: 'acer-33',
    price: 250,
    id: 33,
},
{
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
},
{
    name: 'acer-33',
    price: 250,
    id: 33,
},
{
    name: 'dell-66',
    price: 200,
    id: 12,
},
]

var rlt = {};

items.map(item => {
  let price = item.price
  let name = item.name
  if (rlt[name]) {
    rlt[name] = rlt[name] + price
  } else {
    rlt[name] = price;
  }
});
console.log(rlt);
```

Comment: Why not use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

Comment: we can use reduce too for this. but I was going to show several solution.

Comment: I'm aware :) I'm just asking why you opted not to. I'm curious.

Comment: Thank You, I am So glad you answered, i was wondering if Array#map could ever do this, now i know better, glad to have diverse solutions.

Comment: @ViveeOmomi I'm glad this could help you.

Comment: @Olian04   There is solution that based on reduce. So I made with other method. No any specific reason. :)